# Update/insert DataGridView which is bound to List<T> instead of DataTable?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How to get these edited/updated rows of a `DataGridView` which is bound to `List<T>` instead of a `DataTable`?

Also the last new row (the one with a "*") is gone if a `DataGridView` is bound to `DataTable`?

Does it have to use `DataTable` when building a editable `DataGridView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick solution is to use a `BindingList<T>` instead of a `List<T>`.

That will allow you to add rows to your collection.

Longer term you will want to consider extending the `BindingList`, since the out of the box `BindingList` does not support sorting and other nice things.

Comment: It seems the changed items of `BindingList<T>` can only be captured in the events. It doesn't have `GetChanges()` method like `DataTable`.

Comment: @NickW no - it isn't intended to act as a replacement for a DataTable - it is more for scenarios like where you have an ORM managing your DB access and need to bind domain objects to the grid. Also it is quite easy to implement some sort of dirty tracking on a domain object, just having a flag set in the property setters for example.

Comment: Thanks. I will go back to the "not-strong-typed" `DataTable` for the DataGridViews which need updating/inserting.